# Cannot call Apache Airflow REST API using JavaScript Fetch API (CORs Error)

Tags: javascript, python, airflow

Working with Apache Airflow REST API, and having issues with CORS.

When calling the endpoint using the fetch API in JavaScript I get the following **error**:

```
Access to fetch at 'my_url/api/v1/dags/example_bash_operator/tasks' from origin 'my_url' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
let url = "my_url/api/v1/dags/example_bash_operator/tasks";
let username = 'my_username';
let password = 'my_password';

let headers = new Headers();

headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password));

fetch(url, {
    headers: headers,
    method: 'GET',
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

I also tried adding `mode: 'no-cors'` but just get the "unexpected end of input" error.

For some background, **the following works fine**:

- starting the airflow webserver and scheduler
- accessing the airflow UI
- accessing the SwaggerUI authenticating Swagger and calling the REST endpoints with this tool
- calling my_url in the address bar of a new browser tab (returns the expected JSON)

I have set the `auth_backend` in `airflow.cfg`:

```
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default
```

Although with the latest REST API version I don't think this makes a difference since everything is set to deny.

I have also set the **access control headers** in `airflow.cfg` as described in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/api.html):

```
access_control_allow_headers = origin, content-type, accept
access_control_allow_methods = POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
access_control_allow_origin = my_url
```

...and also tried with wildcard for the `access_control_allow_origin`:

```
access_control_allow_origin = *
```

So the REST calls work fine through Swagger and through the browser address bar, but I cannot call it with fetch using JS. Note that the JS is in an index.html file on the same server (and same root directory) as the airflow files.

Comment: check the browser developer tools console to see if the headers are being received as expected - if not, the problem is on the server code

Comment: I showed the error from the browser console in the question.

Comment: yes you did ... did you check if the headers were being received like I asked?

Comment: yes, headers are being received. The Referrer Policy is "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"

Comment: they must be wrong if you have a CORS error - does your server send response to CROS preflight request (the OPTIONS request sent prior to the actual request)

Comment: CORS preflight OPTIONS requests no longer appear in the network tab of the Chrome developer tools. I'll check another browser. Note that I do see "success" in the console, so something is successful from the fetch, but it's blank.

Comment: Safari says Response:status: 200

Comment: its blank due to CORS, the status can still be 200 though

Comment: @JaromandaX what doesn’t make sense is why the Swagger UI can call the REST API fine. Obviously it’s just using JS as well.

Comment: but not subject to CORS? No idea what a Swagger UI is

Answer (score 0):

The described behavior makes sense, since CORS is used by the browser to prevent attacks from scripts of different resources.
You are still able to fetch via Swagger, Postman or other tools, even through the browser via address bar. But if the policy does not allow to fetch from a different origin, then the browser prevents fetching from your script, which is probably served on a different port. Origin contains host and port.

Your main issue, I cannot help with at the moment.
I've faced the issue of not being able to set the origin policy within the Airflow 2.0 server/API through the (docker-compose) environment variable `AIRFLOW__API__ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN`.
Maybe it's related to your issue, since I can see from the url of your question (containing the v1), that you're are also using Airflow 2.x.

By the way, the message from chrome is `CORS error: Preflight Missing Allow Origin Header`, referring to the question in the comments of the original question.